# Create a fixed size std::vector and write to the elements

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, stdvector, dynamic-arrays

In C++ I wish to allocate a fixed-size (but size determined at runtime) std::vector then write to the elements in this vector. This is the code I am using:

```
int b = 30;
const std::vector<int> test(b);
int &a = test[3];
```

However, this gives me a compiler (MSVC 2010 Pro) error:

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'. Conversion loses qualifiers.

My understanding of const is that it makes all of the member variables of a class constant. For example, the following works fine:

```
class myvec
{
public:
    myvec(int num) : ptr_m(new int[num]) {};
    ~myvec() { delete ptr_m; }
    void resize(int num) { delete ptr_m; ptr_m = new int[num]; }
    int & operator[] (int i) const { return ptr_m[i]; }
    int *ptr_m;
};

const myvec test(30);
int &a = test[3]; // This is fine, as desired
test.resize(10); // Error here, as expected
```

It would therefore seem that std::vector propagates the const-ness of the container to the elements of the vector, which seems odd because if I had wanted the elements to be const I would have used `std::vector<const int>`. This therefore strikes me as a shortcoming of std::vector.

In any case, how can I create a std::vector whose size cannot be changed after construction, but whose elements can be written to?

Comment: Create the variable `a` first, then do your last line.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac: Then `a` is not a reference. The error is caused having a writable reference to an element in the vector, which is exactly what I want.

Comment: You should try using a `std::vector<const int>`... see what happens

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible without writing your own wrapper class. If you want to use  a plain `std::vector`, you have to rely on self-discipline by not using the member functions `insert()`, `push_back()` or `emplace_back()`, either directly or indirectly (e.g. via a `back_inserter`).

Note that there is a current proposal for [dynamic arrays](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3532.html) for the new C++14 Standard:

> [...] we propose to define a new facility for arrays where the number of
>   elements is bound at construction. We call these dynamic arrays,
>   dynarray.

The proposal actually comes with a reference implementation that you can use in your own code (make sure to change `namespace std` into something else for the time being).

```
namespace std {
template< class T >
struct dynarray
{
    // types:
    typedef       T                               value_type;
    typedef       T&                              reference;
    typedef const T&                              const_reference;
    typedef       T*                              iterator;
    typedef const T*                              const_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<iterator>       reverse_iterator;
    typedef std::reverse_iterator<const_iterator> const_reverse_iterator;
    typedef size_t                                size_type;
    typedef ptrdiff_t                             difference_type;

    // fields:
private:
    T*        store;
    size_type count;

    // helper functions:
    void check(size_type n)
        { if ( n >= count ) throw out_of_range("dynarray"); }
    T* alloc(size_type n)
        { if ( n > std::numeric_limits<size_type>::max()/sizeof(T) )
              throw std::bad_array_length();
          return reinterpret_cast<T*>( new char[ n*sizeof(T) ] ); }

public:
    // construct and destruct:
    dynarray() = delete;
    const dynarray operator=(const dynarray&) = delete;

    explicit dynarray(size_type c)
        : store( alloc( c ) ), count( c )
        { size_type i;
          try {
              for ( size_type i = 0; i < count; ++i )
                  new (store+i) T;
          } catch ( ... ) {
              for ( ; i > 0; --i )
                 (store+(i-1))->~T();
              throw;
          } }

    dynarray(const dynarray& d)
        : store( alloc( d.count ) ), count( d.count )
        { try { uninitialized_copy( d.begin(), d.end(), begin() ); }
          catch ( ... ) { delete store; throw; } }

    ~dynarray()
        { for ( size_type i = 0; i < count; ++i )
              (store+i)->~T();
          delete[] store; }

    // iterators:
    iterator       begin()        { return store; }
    const_iterator begin()  const { return store; }
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return store; }
    iterator       end()          { return store + count; }
    const_iterator end()    const { return store + count; }
    const_iterator cend()   const { return store + count; }

    reverse_iterator       rbegin()       
        { return reverse_iterator(end()); }
    const_reverse_iterator rbegin()  const
        { return reverse_iterator(end()); }
    reverse_iterator       rend()         
        { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }
    const_reverse_iterator rend()    const
        { return reverse_iterator(begin()); }

    // capacity:
    size_type size()     const { return count; }
    size_type max_size() const { return count; }
    bool      empty()    const { return count == 0; }

    // element access:
    reference       operator[](size_type n)       { return store[n]; }
    const_reference operator[](size_type n) const { return store[n]; }

    reference       front()       { return store[0]; }
    const_reference front() const { return store[0]; }
    reference       back()        { return store[count-1]; }
    const_reference back()  const { return store[count-1]; }

    const_reference at(size_type n) const { check(n); return store[n]; }
    reference       at(size_type n)       { check(n); return store[n]; }

    // data access:
    T*       data()       { return store; }
    const T* data() const { return store; }
};

} // namespace std
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the dynarray implementation. I'm also seeking an adequate explanation as to why `const std::vector<int>` means the same thing as `const std::vector<const int>`, when it could instead mean exactly what the std::dynarray is proposed for, forgoing the need for a new container.

Comment: @user664303 You cannot put a `const T` into a container because such a type is not Assignable and therefore violates the Container Requirements. Putting `const` in front of the container itself, effectively disables all non-const member functions, including element assignment. That's why you really need either a container adapter that selectively disables only resizing members, or a special purpose class like `dynarray`.

Answer (score 2):

The actual error is because you declare the vector to be *constant*, meaning you can never change the contents.

Then when you try to get a non-constant reference to an entry in the vector, the compiler tells you that you can't do that, because then you could change the constant value stored in the vector.

---

As for creating a vector with a size that can be fixed at runtime, but not change size after the vector has been created, then you have to create a container adaptor. Basically you have to create a wrapper around another container, just like e.g. `std::stack` does.

Comment: const means I cannot change the member variables of the vector instance. However, I would have thought that the elements of the vector are not members of the instance, only that their pointer is. The pointer should not point to const elements as I did not use std::vector<const int>. So it strikes me as odd that I cannot change the elements.

Comment: @user664303 By making the vector `const` you tell the compiler that _all_ of the vector is constant, not only the size but also its content.

Comment: Clearly, in the case of std::vector, yes. But this is not standard behaviour. See my updated question. So why does std::vector do this? Especially bearing in mind that I would have used a const type if I'd wanted const elements. Nobody has adequately justified the behaviour to me yet.

Comment: To put it succinctly, why does `const std::vector<int>` mean the same thing as `const std::vector<const int>`, when it could mean something different and forgo the need for a new std::dynarray class?

Comment: @user664303 I haven't checked the standard yet, but both clang and GCC complains about it, so I would say it's they way it's supposed to be.

Comment: I see. There was a bug in the first version of the code, now fixed. Are you suggesting that my understanding is wrong and that my compiler is not correctly enforcing the standard? Could well be. Can anyone else confirm?

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is that you cannot do that: you cannot define the vector as const and then add members to it.

As others have pointed out, the new standard offers the array class, which is probably more suitable for what you are doing.

If you are interested in a fixed length, the most related method in vector you can be interested in is `reserve()`, which will set the `vector<>` to the size of the given parameter, making vector expansions unnecessary.

If you cannot use Std C++11, then you need to create a wrapper class that does not let you modify the vector. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class FinalVector {
public:
    FinalVector(unsigned int size)
        { v.reserve( size ); }
    const T &at(unsigned int i) const
        { return v.at( i ); }
    T &at(unsigned int i)
        { return v.at( i ); }
    T &operator[](unsigned int i)
        { return at( i ); }
    const T &operator[](unsigned int i) const
        { return at( i ); }
    void push_back(const T &x);
    size_t size() const
        { return v.size(); }
    size_t capacity() const
        { return v.size(); }
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};

template<typename T>
void FinalVector<T>::push_back(const T &x)
{
    if ( v.size() < v.capacity() ) {
        v.push_back( x );
    } else {
        throw runtime_error( "vector size exceeded" );
    }
}

int main()
{
    FinalVector<int> v( 3 );

    v.push_back( 1 );
    v.push_back( 2 );
    v.push_back( 3 );

    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        cout << v[ i ] << endl;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not adding members. The vector is allocated to be the correct size on construction. No problem there. The issue arises when I wish to write to the elements. But yes, it looks like I am going to need a wrapper.